# Find viewers who have viewed all movies of all types

Tags: mysql, sql

With the given schema that represents movies that people have viewed: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0801e7693a6383477c0719f94f26e347)

How could I find all of the viewers who have "viewed" (movie_id is associated with one of their history_id) all movies from all categories AND all viewers who have "viewed" at least one movie from each category that contains a movie.

```
Expected Output
  viewer_id
     4
     8
```

Where viewer 4 fits the former and viewer 8 fits the latter.
I figured the former condition can be found by querying for the count of the movies table(since that holds all movies for every category), and comparing it against the count of all the movies that a viewer has watched (joining viewing_history and history_items, grouping by customer id and finding counts). Not sure how to go about this, as I'm currently stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This following logic should work for you. But according to your provided data, neither id 4 nor 8 is coming as output as none of them meet your criteria. id 4 viewed 10 out of 11 movies and id 8 viewed 3 category movie from 4 category. you can check the [Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=839db9e22f5e3afb889467217a4b54b0).

```
SELECT A.viewer_ID
FROM viewers A
INNER JOIN viewing_history B ON A.viewer_ID = B.viewer_ID
INNER JOIN view_items C ON B.history_ID =C.history_ID
INNER JOIN movies D ON C.movie_ID = D.movie_ID
INNER JOIN categories E ON D.category_ID = E.category_ID
GROUP BY A.viewer_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C.movie_ID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM movies)
OR COUNT(DISTINCT D.category_ID) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT category_ID) FROM movies)
```

With correct data, this above query should work.

Comment: Gotcha on the first part, but what does "id 8 viewed 3 category movie from 4 category" mean exactly? The fourth category has no movies associated with it, so it should not be considered

Comment: @GregPallermo Updated the Fiddle and answer. Hope this will help.